# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when execute my program

Tags: c

i am begginer at c programming and i wrote program and trying to run my program via terminal

from terminal:

```
 $ ./Countries 2 /home/david/CLionProjects/untitled/dddd.txt
```

i get the error:

```
  message: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

but when i run my program with my Clion its work perfectly.
i tried to debug with dbg and i found the error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_IO_fgets (buf=0x7fffffffdc00 "", n=300, fp=0x0) at iofgets.c:47
47  iofgets.c: No such file or directory.
```

its seems that my program cant read the file dddd.txt and i cant understand why .

my main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Countries.h"
#include "Countries.c"
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    {

        int fortest= atoi(argv[1]); //number of Countries

        char *useForString; // use us to points to string use like name of country or city or food
        int incrementCountry = -1;// increment every time when enter country from input
        FILE *fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");
        int chooseOfclient;  //input from client number between 1-6
        char singLine[300]; //char array for the line from text
        Country **Atlas = buildCountry(fortest);  //build Countries arraywhile ((ch != '\n') && (ch != EOF))
        while (fgets(singLine, sizeof(singLine), fp))
        {//while1

            if (singLine[0] != '\t') {//if
                incrementCountry++;
                useForString = cutNameOfcountry(singLine);
                Atlas[incrementCountry] = inputNewCountry(useForString, cutCordiantesLeft(singLine),
                                                          cutCordiantesRight(singLine));
                free(useForString); // free the memory from heap that allocate inside cutNameOfCountr
                continue;
            }//if
            City *pCity = cutCityData(singLine);
            buildCity(Atlas[incrementCountry], pCity);
        }//while
return (0)
}
```

Comment: It seems that the problem is related to `fgets()` receiving `NULL` as pointer to file (fp=0x00 in the error), so check the result of `fopen()` with `perror()`, also `#include <std`lib.h> if you are using `free()`

Comment: yeah , this is the problem : Error: : No such file or directory
Segmentation fault (core dumped)          
idea how can i fix it?

Comment: Have you checked the result of `perror("fopen")`?  "No such file" is pretty descriptive :P

Comment: i added if after the line FILE *fp = fopen(argv[2], "r"); 

if(fp==NULL)
            perror("Error: ");

and than tried to execute again and got : Error : No such file or directory
but if build and run my program via Clion , its work perfectly